# How to show iframe after button click

Tags: javascript, html

So i am trying to have my iframe hidden on the page, until i click this button, but for some reason when the website loades the iframe is already there, i can hide it with the button, but im trying to have it hidden from the start.

```css
var iframeShowing=false;
function show() {
  var iframe1=document.getElementById("iframe");
  iframe1.style.display=iframeShowing ? "block": "none";
  iframeShowing=!iframeShowing;
}
```

```html
<form> <button type="button" id="files" onclick="show()">Database</button> </form>
<iframe id="iframe" frameBorder='no' src="https://databank.worldbank.org/embed/Mine/id/f1b36ffc?ti=y&ds=n&dd=y&tb=y&sh=y&dw=y&pr=y&inf=y&zm=y&md=y&navigator=n&theme=darkGrey&bdrClr=rgb(68,68,68)&bdrStyle=solid&bdrWidth=0px&title=Arial;16px;true;false;rgb(68,68,68);justify&exptypes=Excel,CSV,TabbedTxt"
  width="600" height="460"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript has nice function for that (`classList.toggle`). And i suggest to start loading the table if somebody clicked the button. If you have many tables on your side the page will be very slow. I have included it as an example.

```js
function show() {
  const f = document.getElementById('myiframe');  
  const link = 'https://databank.worldbank.org/embed/Mine/id/f1b36ffc?ti=y&ds=n&dd=y&tb=y&sh=y&dw=y&pr=y&inf=y&zm=y&md=y&navigator=n&theme=darkGrey&bdrClr=rgb(68,68,68)&bdrStyle=solid&bdrWidth=0px&title=Arial;16px;true;false;rgb(68,68,68);justify&exptypes=Excel,CSV,TabbedTxt';
  document.getElementById('waiting').innerText = " - please wait";
  f.classList.toggle('hide');
  f.setAttribute('src', link);
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form> 
    <button type="button" id="files" onclick="show()">Database<span id="waiting"></span></button> 
</form>
<iframe class="hide" id="myiframe" frameBorder='no' src="" width= "600"  height="460" >...</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid the inline "onclick" tag inside iframe, and I'd wrap everything inside a domcontentloaded callback:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var iframeShowing = false;
        var iframe1 = document.getElementById('iframe');
        iframe1.style.display = "none"
        iframe1.addEventListener("click", show);

        function show() {
            iframe1.style.display = iframeShowing ? 'block' : 'none';
            iframeShowing = !iframeShowing;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It doesnt work, its hidden when the page loads, but when i click the button it doesnt show up.

Comment: I Edited the answer, try that

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) methods in Vanilla JavaScript to manipulate the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction), precisely `.hide` class in this case.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("files");
const iframe = document.querySelector("#iframe");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  iframe.classList.toggle("hide");
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <button type="button" id="files">Database</button>
</form>
<iframe class="hide" id="iframe" frameborder="no" src="https://databank.worldbank.org/embed/Mine/id/f1b36ffc?ti=y&ds=n&dd=y&tb=y&sh=y&dw=y&pr=y&inf=y&zm=y&md=y&navigator=n&theme=darkGrey&bdrClr=rgb(68,68,68)&bdrStyle=solid&bdrWidth=0px&title=Arial;16px;true;false;rgb(68,68,68);justify&exptypes=Excel,CSV,TabbedTxt" width="600" height="460"></iframe>
```